# Is it possible to SET a multidimensional array new value, for layers deeper than the first one, by passing its coordinate in a string?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider the following code sample which better illustrates my question:

```
<?php

$array['a']['b']['c'] = 'value of c';

$coordinates_for_c_key = "['a']['b']['c']";

$array{$coordinates_for_c_key} = 'new value of c';

print $array{$coordinates_for_c_key};

// Output: new value of c
```

Is there a way to accomplish the above proposal?

Comment: Why not just store the values 'a' 'b' and 'c'?

Comment: Using `eval` you can use pretty much any expression as a string, but it will be slow.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can get it done:

```
<?php

$arr['a']['b']['c'] = 'value of c';
$coordinates_for_c_key = "['a']['b']['c']";

function set_array_value(&$arr, $key, $val) {
  eval("\$arr".$key." = '".$val."';");
}

print_r($arr);
set_array_value($arr, $coordinates_for_c_key, "new value of c");
print_r($arr);

?>
```